# Can't assign echo statement

Tags: php, echo

I have this code:-

```
<?php

  $value = echo $row['balance'];

?>
```

And the mistake is in `$value = echo $row['balance'];` and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Remove that echo. It is incorrect.

Comment: `$value =  $row['balance']; echo $value;`

Comment: *"The mistake is in $value = echo $row['balance']; So I can't find the mistake"* First you say that you know where the mistake is and then you don't know it in the next sentence? Also why don't you show us the error message? And if you already do it, have you put that error message into google?

Comment: `echo $value = $row['balance'];` can be done in one shot also. @Anant ;-) in most cases. It's valid syntax.

Comment: @Anant Hard to say where they're "echoing" it though ;-) If it's just *"sitting there doing nothing...."* lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `echo`:-

```
$value = $row['balance'];
```

Additional (check `$row['balance']` is set or not other wise undefined index error may occur):-

```
<?php
if(isset($row['balance'])):
  $value = $row['balance']; 
  if($value > 29 ):
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="myButton">Ticket kaufen! 1 Ticket = 30 dM</button>';
  else:
    echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="myButton" disabled>Du hast nicht genug Geld!</button>'; 
  endif;
  endif;
?>
```

Also if you want to `echo` that value simply do:- `echo $value;`

Comment: nein sprachen sie deutsch lol! Looks like German to me, yes?

Comment: @Fred-ii-   may be i don't know. :):):)

Comment: where did you get the *Ticket kaufen!* etc. from? *hahaha!*

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i am not concentrating on the language at that time :):). still i didn't try to find out the language. you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is wrong:

```
  $value = echo $row['balance']; // no need to use echo
```

Remove the `echo`:

```
  $value = $row['balance'];
```

Which would have thrown you a syntax error using error reporting.

Comment: Thanks! :) It works!